# SVN error while taking checkout using script

Tags: bash, shell, svn, jenkins

I am getting below error when taking checkout from svn using a script.

```
**[Test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson8576425899836211909.sh
+ sh /cvsrx/rxapp/build_dir/Jenkins_Scripts/test.sh
Could not load program svn:
Could not load module /opt/freeware/lib/libssl.so.
    Dependent module /usr/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.1) could not be loaded.
    Member libcrypto.so.1.0.1 is not found in archive 
Could not load module svn.
    Dependent module /opt/freeware/lib/libssl.so could not be loaded.
Could not load module .
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE**
```

In test.sh I have written just one line svn co /path to svn branch/ 
I am in middle of some test so please don't ask why am not using jenkins in build svn plugin.
here,I am able to take checkout on command prompt using svn co /path to svn branch/
But not if I write this command line in script and run in execute shell of jenkins.
Any help please ?

Am using jenkins on AIX 7 platform.

I had softlinks from /usr/bin/svn to /opt/freeware/bin/svn.SVN installed at /opt/freeware/bin/svn ..... By default when i do which svn its showing `/usr/bin/svn`But When i deleted those softlinks and exported path,Jenkins didnt recognize SVN at all.And `which svn` command doesnot show any svn installed . PFB logs of jenkins :
`

```
/bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson5607872610124977868.sh
+ export PATH=/opt/freeware/bin/svn/:/opt/freeware/bin/svnversion:/opt/freeware/bin/svn:/opt/freeware/bin/svnversion/:/usr/java5/lib:/opt/freeware/bin/svnversion/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R7/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/gnome/bin:/opt/kde3/bin:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/sbin:/
+ echo /opt/freeware/bin/svn/:/opt/freeware/bin/svnversion:/opt/freeware/bin/svn:/opt/freeware/bin/svnversion/:/usr/java5/lib:/opt/freeware/bin/svnversion/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R7/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/gnome/bin:/opt/kde3/bin:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/sbin:/opt/freeware/bin/svn/:/opt/freeware/bin/svnversion:/opt/freeware/bin/svn:/opt/freeware/bin/svnversion/:/usr/java5/lib:/opt/freeware/bin/svnversion/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R7/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/gnome/bin:/opt/kde3/bin:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/sbin
+ cd /usr/local/apps/Jenkins_new/scripts
+ ./test.sh
Could not load program /opt/freeware/bin/svn:
Could not load module /opt/freeware/lib/libssl.so.
    Dependent module /usr/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.1) could not be loaded.
    Member libcrypto.so.1.0.1 is not found in archive 
Could not load module svn.
    Dependent module /opt/freeware/lib/libssl.so could not be loaded.
Could not load module .
./test.sh[3]: svn:  not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE`
```

Comment: it's impossible for me to ask why you're not using the jenkins svn plugin.  why are you not using the jenkins svn plugin?  This is the solution to your problem. (or you're solving the wrong problem)

Comment: I am using some commands like `svn info and svn --version` in our scripts.Also doing a small checkout from different branch.Hence canot use jenkins by default svn plugin.It will be great if i can override jenkins plugin by my system's command line svn.  ..

Comment: you can get those values directly from jenkins... checking out from two different branches is a bad move - sounds like your source isn't laid out well.  you're making your problems for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

ReInstalling Jenkins solved my problem !! It was due to corrupt plugin which happened due to server restart.
Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen the exact command of svn you have used in test.sh, but would advice you to give full path of SVN in your calling line, eg /usr/bin/svn co .....
And if also possible make an entry in your test.sh for export PATH and export LD_LIBRARY_PATH setting them to values which are paths of the mentioned .so files

Comment: I already told that I am ust using "svn co " command :::: svn co https://corp/svn/      ,,,, This command is working when executed at command line of server but not when written in script and execute it afterwards

Comment: I also exported path for the lib and svn still am gettign the same erro. very much confused now

Comment: Did you try locating the .so and .a files and exporting their respective paths in LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Comment: Yes I did first .... But it didnt work.Then I tried using `export LIBPATH` !! wow It worked !1 I have envplugin from which this idea struck me out.But to my surprise why LD_LIBRARAY_PATH didnot work ?

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using Hudson/Jenkins. Hudson and Jenkins use SVNKit internally when checking stuff in and out of Subversion. This means that the command line `svn` client may not be installed on your system, or that it may have other problems.

It is also possible that there are multiple `svn` clients on your system. For example, you may have one under `/usr/bin/svn` and one under `/usr/local/bin/svn`. If Subversion is working from the command line, but not in the script, you may have a different `$PATH` setup when you're executing from the command line vs. the script from Hudson/Jenkins. You can add to your script (if it's BASH) the line `type svn` to see where your executing `svn` from. It may be different from what you are using from the command line. It may also be nice to print out `$PATH` as part of your script.

It would also be helpful to see the `svn` command that your script is executing, and tell us what you're trying to do. You can also add to your script the following lines:

```
PS4="\$LINE: "
set -xv
```

These lines will turn on shell script debugging, and help you locate where your script is having problems.

This will give you some clues as to what is going wrong in your script.

## Reply

> Thanks David. Here only 1 svn path exists (usr/bin/svn)but created as a softlink see -->cd /usr/bin/svn lrwxrwxrwx 1 root system 26 Jul 1 14:34 svn -> ../../opt/freeware/bin/svn. Also soflink of libs.so is created see --> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root system 15 Sep 13 18:15 libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.0.1 .......... Is it possible that softlink is creating these problems ?? Before requesting to remove these softlinks ,i need confirmation that these softlinks are creating problems.

Softlinking isn't unusual for Unix. For example, I have Ant, Grails, Maven, Subversion, and many other packages installed under `/opt` on my Mac. In order not to have to include each and every one of these in my path, I soft link all of the binaries for those programs under `/usr/local/bin`. About 80% of the *programs* under `/usr/local/bin` are merely soft links elsewhere.

Library soft links are also very common. This usually has to do with version numbering. When a program requests a library, it may or may not include the library's version number. So, you have `libfoo-2.0.3.so` on your drive. This is the actual version of *foo*. However, few programs will request that particular version. Instead, they may simply request they need Version #2 of foo or just say they need to link to foo.

To handle this, you will have `libfoo2.0.3.so` soft linked to `libfoo-2.so` for programs that specify they need version 2 of *foo*. Then, `libfoo-2.so` will be soft linked to `libfoo.so`. This way, libfoo will be called no matter what. If I install, `libfoo2.0.4.so`, I can change the link to `libfoo-2.so` to point to version 2.0.4 instead of version 2.0.3, and anything that depends upon Foo will be picking up the correct version.

Instead, let's look at the error message:

> Could not load module /opt/freeware/lib/libssl.so.
>    Dependent module ***/usr/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.1) could not be loaded.***
>    Member libcrypto.so.1.0.1 is not found in archive

For some reason, it couldn't access the file `/usr/lib/libcryto.a`. Is this file on you machine? Is it in `/usr/lib`? If not, where is it located?

So, where did you get this version of Subversion from? Why is the link to the `/opt/freeware/bin/` directory?  Was this part of your system?

It could be that Subversion on your system is not complete and never did work. In Jenkins, the Subversion repository is accessed by the SVNKit Jarfile which is embedded inside Jenkins/Hudson itself, so it wouldn't really be a surprise to find that the Subversion binary didn't work.

Are you able to do anything with Subversion from the command line? If not, you may have to install a new version of Subversion from [Perzl](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Subversion) which is where CollabNet points to for an AIX version of Subversion. (It's at least up to date at version 1.8.4).

You may even want to change the soft link at `/usr/bin/svn` to point to the newer, working version of Subversion.

Comment: Thanks David. Here only 1 svn path exists (usr/bin/svn)but created as a softlink see -->`cd /usr/bin/svn ` `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root system 26 Jul 1 14:34 svn -> ../../opt/freeware/bin/svn.` Also soflink of libs.so is created see --> `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root system 15 Sep 13 18:15 libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.0.1` .......... Is it possible that softlink is creating these problems ?? Before requesting to remove these softlinks ,i need confirmation that these softlinks are creating problems

Comment: Thanks David for a proper explaination.SVN is installed at location --> `/opt/freeware/bin/` which has softlink to `/usr/bin/svn`.I dont think there is any problem with SVN on this system as I am able to execute any svn command on command line.But not via script in jenkins.Today ,I tried removing soft link  and export path to `opt/freeware/bin/svn` but then jenkins didn't recognize svn at all. I think there is some mismatch between our svn server and svn plugin installed in jenkins.But still no clue ... Any idea now ?

Comment: Don't remove the softlink! There is something going on if SVN works on the  command line, but not the script. Log in as the user who actually executes Jenkins/Hudson and see where that `svn` command is coming from! Can you execute the script w/o going through Jenkins as the Jenkins user?

Comment: Thanks David !! ISSUE resolved now I set `export LIBPATH` which was by default to /usr/bin and I reset to `/opt/freeware/lib`.